# visual studio c++. Code style access modifier without line break (on the same line as member)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 17.9.4 with sharper C++.

I want to configure the code formatting settings so that the member access modifier fits on the same line as my member's type and name.
Without line break after access modifier colon.

example:

before

```
class Foo
{
    private: 
    int member;
};
```

after

```
class Foo
{
    private: int member;
};
```

I didn't find the line break settings for the access modifier either in "Visual Studio -> Options -> Text editor -> c/c++" or in "Resharper -> Options -> Code editing -> c++"

Is it possible to customize formatter this way? maybe with the help of some visual studio extension

Comment: If your class had multiple members would you expect the access modifier to be prefixed in front of each? Seems like unnecessary code noise to me.

Comment: Yes i will expect each one to be prefixed. I will be able to easily see what modifier member has, and don't worry about some macro changing it. 9 more symbols for me its not a big deal even on laptop screen

Comment: You do whatever you like with your own code, however this will totally irritate anyone that you might share your code with. This is just not how you write C++ code.

Comment: BoP, You're not right, we're writing the code as agreed in the team. This is not the way You write c++. But i like this style